# Use _roff to underline words

Tags: less

I currently have a file that I'd like to pass through a `_roff` to format with underline a few words in the file, and then view the file in `less`.  Just a few, mind you, not whole sections or anything.

**How do i underline specific words in a file with `_roff`?**

NB:  I know I have groff and nroff.
NNB:  I don't know a whole lot about type formatting.

Answer (score 2):

At least with groff (I'm not sure it's portable), `.ul` gives you underline.

```
groff -Tascii <'<EOF'
This is a single line
.ul
with four underlined words
and more non-underline words.
EOF
```

If the only formatting you want is underlining, there may be an easier way. For example `less` automatically converts the sequence character-backspace-underscore (or underscore-backspace-character) to the underlined character; it also converts character-backspace-character to boldface.

```
echo $'one u\b_n\b_d\b_e\b_r\b_l\b_i\b_n\b_e\b_d\b_ word' | less
```

Comment: Your second suggestion - is this something less-specific?  It sounds rather magical.

Comment: @sheepsimulator: Yes. See the description of the `-u` and `-U` in the `less` manual. Another less trick: `LESS='+/  -u' man less`