# How to use the ul command line utility

Tags: command-line, terminal, utilities, util-linux

I wanted to answer [Use _roff to underline words](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/use-roff-to-underline-words) with "just use ul, this command is meant specifically for underlining text", however I just can't grasp how to use it. I thought

```
$ echo "hello _kitty_ world" > /tmp/foo.txt
$ ul /tmp/foo.txt
```

would give me an underlined "kitty", however it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The input format requires character-backspace-underscore or character-backspace-letter to underline a character. You also get boldface with character-backspace-character.

```
echo $'hello k\b_i\b_t\b_t\b_y\b_ world' | ul
```

Less does a similar transformation automatically.

Comment: To enter Backspace in vim, press [strg] + [v] in INSERT mode and then enter 08.

Comment: _\bf_\bo_\bo will also work.

Comment: @echox: for the non-Germanophones in the audience, that's `Ctrl+V`. And a handier way is `Ctrl+V Ctrl+H` (`Ctrl+V Backspace` may or may not give the right character depending on your terminal configuration.)

Comment: In some cases it may be better to write the underlines first so if you just `cat` the text to a normal terminal you will see the text rather than the underscores. Compare `echo $'hello k\b_i\b_t\b_t\b_y\b_ world'` and `echo $'hello _\bk_\bi_\bt_\bt_\by world'` for example. Both will generate the same output with `ul` and `less`.